# Through: how to use it with subtraction of functions?

Tags: syntax, functional-style

As the documentation says the command `Through` works as it follows:

```
f[x_]=x;
g[x_]=x^2;
Through[(f+g)[x]]

--> x + x^2
```

Like this, I also expect it works as below:

```
Through[(f-g)[x]]

--> x - x^2
```

It, however, returns:

```
Through[(f-g)[x]]

--> x + (-g)[x]
```

Do you guys know how to make Mathematica return as I expect for the subtraction?

I use Mathematica11.1 on Windows10 64bit.

Comment: Taiki, you might want to use `SetDelayed (:=)` instead of `Set (=)` when defining `f` and `g` (i.e., `ClearAll[f, g]; f[x_]:= x` and `g[x_]:= x^2` ) if you want `Through[(f + g)[z]]` to give `z+z^2` (not `f[z]+g[z]`).

Comment: @kglr I don't see any difference between `SetDelayed(:=)` and `Set(=)` in this case. I understand general definitions of `SetDelayed(:=)` and `Set(=)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand what's happening always check the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of your expresion.

```
FullForm[(f - g)[x]]

(* Plus[f,Times[-1,g]] *)
```

That is the expression *Mathematica* is working with internally.
Probably you were expecting `Subtract[f, g][x]`, but that is not the case.

You could [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) the `Times[-1,#]` with `Composition[Minus,#]`.

```
Through[(f-g)[x]]/.Times[-1,q_]->Composition[Minus,q]
(* f[x]-g[x] *)

%//FullForm
(* Plus[f[x],Times[-1,g[x]]] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can compose [`Minus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minus.html) with `g` use it with `Plus`:

```
Through[(f + Minus @* g)[x]]
```

> x - x^2

Other ways:

```
Through[(f + (-g @ # &))[x]]
```

> x - x^2

```
Through[(f + (-#&) @* g)[x]]
```

> x - x^2

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes want to apply a linear combination of functions to an argument.  This can be more difficult if the linear combinations are generated by code, so that rewriting them some form to make `Through` convenient is difficult.  So I usually use a utility like the following:

```
linearThrough[(Optional[a_?NumericQ] f_ + Optional[b_?NumericQ] g_)[x__]] :=
  a f[x] + b g[x];
```

OP's example:

```
linearThrough[(f - g)[x]]
(*  f[x] - g[x]  *)
```

---

You can also use `Subtract` ***if*** you prevent it from evaluating to `Plus[f, Times[-1, g]]` prematurely:

```
Through[Unevaluated@Subtract[f, g][x]]
(*  f[x] - g[x]  *)
```

---

Since I somewhat broadened the scope by bring in linear combinations of functions, here is a similar utility, in which the linear operators are specified as a argument, everything else is assumed to be constant:

```
linearOperate[heads_List][comb_[x__]] :=
  (comb /. F : Alternatives @@ heads :> F[x]) /;
   Internal`LinearQ[comb, heads] || FreeQ[comb, Alternatives @@ heads];
```

Examples:

```
linearOperate[{f, g}][(f - g)[x]]
(*  f[x] - g[x]  *)

linearOperate[{f, g, h}][(a f - g + h - b + 9)[x]]
(*  9 - b + a f[x] - g[x] + h[x]  *)

linearOperate[{f, g, h}][(a f)[x]]
(*  a f[x]  *)

linearOperate[{f, g, h}][(3)[x]]
(*  3  *)
```

This last example is the reason for the extra test, `... || FreeQ[comb, Alternatives @@ heads]`: [`` Internal`LinearQ ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103004/4999) says a constant is not linear:

```
Internal`LinearQ[3, {f, g, h}]
(*  False  *)
```